# Tinder App on Meteor

Tags: mobile, meteor, elasticsearch, gps, scalability

I'm building an "generic tinder" mobile app where I must find people that are close to me (like 100m, 1km, etc)
Could you guys tell me if im going in the right direction?
I'm using Elastic Search to check distance, it's really cool, with 800 users , it can calculate who is under 100m radius in like 3ms.
**the problem is** : synchronize the position of the users with the meteor server and then the server ElasticSearch server.
On each client, I watch the mobile's GPS position and whenever it changes , I call a server method that updates the mongo database and also sends an update request to ElasticSearch server to update the position there too
(im using GeoHash with 3m precision)
I'm concerned about scalability issues.
**1.** Should the clients send their position directly to the ElasticSearch server?
If so, how can I authenticate them?
**2.** On the mobile client app, should I watch for every single change on position or code some timing algorithm?
**2.** Do you have any other approaches on how to build this kind of relation client-server?

Thanks! I Really need your help, guys!

Answer (score 0):

My opinion:

1. No, sending the position to the MongoDB via a Meteor method first is best
2. Definitely don't watch for every single change. I recommend a timing algorithm that checks every 5 minutes (how far can you travel in 5 min unless you're on an airplane?).
3. Professional developers use something called [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff). You can be fancy and do this like: a) Wait 1 min and check for location change,
   b) If no change, wait 2 mins and check,
   c) If no change, wait 4 mins and check,
   d) If no change, wait 8 mins and check,
   e) Well, you get the idea. You can set a max of 16 mins if you want.
   Note that this is what [Google uses to handle errors](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors).